# What is the difference between aggregate and group_by in R when I try to sum up a few columns which are grouped by a few criterias

Tags: python, r, porting

I am trying to convert some R code(not written by me) to python code for a project. The R code uses aggregate() to do some grouped sum up, but when I try to replicate the action in Python by using .groupby, the result differs. R code yields dataframe with 479000+ rows whereas Python yields 489000+ rows.

It turns out later, I discovered that R also has this group_by() function and when used on that huge dataframe, the result is the same as what .groupby yields in Python

```
test <- df %>% group_by(A, B, C) %>% 
  summarise(D= sum(D, na.rm=TRUE), E= sum(E,na.rm=TRUE))


test <- aggregate(x=list(D= df$D, E= df$E), by=list(A= df$A, B= df$B, C=df$C), 
                  FUN=function(x) sum(x, na.rm=TRUE))
```

```
test= df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'],as_index=False)['D', 'E'].agg('sum')
```

I am almost surely confident that I didn't mess up on the coding, since the project I work on put emphasis on confidentiality, the above codes is the best I can provide, sorry in advance.

It is obvious that at least one of these approaches are wrong and two functions must operate in different ways to cause that. I would really wish to know the difference between them and which function is correct in achieving what I need(namely). Thank you very much.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem, but we would really need some example data to demonstrate the issue. When I tried it on the mtcars dataset I could not reproduce your results

Comment: can you show the output of `df %>% distinct(A,B,C) %>% nrow()`

Comment: @Potato_Noodle We don't want all the data anyway. A minimal self-contained [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038) is required. Cheers.

Comment: The first version with `group_by` includes `NA` as a grouping level for `A B C`, even though it removes `NA`s from the `sum` of `D E`.  The `aggregate` version does not include `NA` grouping levels.

Comment: I hate to say this but the problem lies within the previous steps of my code, which has nothing to do with the functions I mentioned in the question. Sorry to disappoint  :(   . All comments are sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know thee exact reason, but here is one potential issue with `aggregate` with `na.action`.  By default, it can remove the rows with `NA`.  An option is to add `na.action = na.pass`

Using a reproducible example

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = rep(letters[1:4], each = 4), 
     col2 =  sample(c(1:5, NA), 16, replace = TRUE), col3 =  NA)
```

extreme case where one column is all NA

```
aggregate(.~ col1, df1, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

> Error in aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) :    no
>   rows to aggregate

```
aggregate(.~ col1, df1, sum, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = na.pass)
#  col1 col2 col3
#1    a   13    0
#2    b    5    0
#3    c   11    0
#4    d   16    0
```

So, depending upon the number of NAs anywhere in the columns, that row could be dropped out and this would reflect in the calculation